How do I send PDF Attachment/sender a copy when using Xero Invoice/:id/Email endpoint?
When sending an Invoice using the Invoice/:id/Email endpoint, I am hoping to be able to attach a PDF copy of the invoice and optionally send a copy to the invoice sender. In the UI, both of these options are available.
Is there a way to achieve sending the PDF as an attachment and/or send a copy to the sender via the API?
I noticed at https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/requests-and-responses that the Accept header can be used when retrieving invoices, but I have not been able to find any documentation to attach the PDF invoice on send on that page or the Invoices API docs (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices).

It is not currently possible to send attachments when emailing invoices from Xero.
You can add your vote for the feature here

Thank you for replying. I have voted. Hopefully this is added
